# How extract images from array and put inside list

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I have dropdownlist

```
<select id="animal">
<option>Choose animal </option>
<option value="1">animal 1 </option>
<option value="2">animal 2</option>
<option value="3">animal 3 </option>
</select>
```

And 2 dimensional array of images sources:

```
var pictureList = [
    ["images/img1.jpg","images/img2.jpg"],
    ["images/img3.jpg","images/img4.jpg", "images/img5.jpg"],
    ["images/img6.jpg"]
];
```

I can't create a script which will extract images from array and insert them into one images list. For example, if I choose "animal 1" option, I will get

```
 <ul id="slider"> 
  <li><img class="imageClass" src="images/img1.jpg"/></li>
  <li><img class="imageClass" src="images/img2.jpg"/></li>       
 <ul>
```

For "animal 2"

```
  <ul id="slider"> 
   <li><img class="imageClass" src="images/img3.jpg"/></li>
   <li><img class="imageClass" src="images/img4.jpg"/></li> 
   <li><img class="imageClass" src="images/img5.jpg"/></li>      
  <ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase what you asked for:

> You need to select one animal, and print on the screen the list of images associated with that animal.

All you need is to get the value of the selected animal and query the respective position in array and use that array to print the HTML. [I wrote this plunkr for you](http://plnkr.co/edit/mvJwC3z3MX9Qm8guWylA?p=info):

```
$('#animal').change(function () {
    var animalImages = pictureList[$(this).val() - 1];

    $('#slider').html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < animalImages.length; i++) {
      $('#slider').append('<li><img class="imageClass" src="' + animalImages[i] + '" /></li>');
    }
});
```

I didn't run the

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run loop over your 2 D array. You can do something like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < pictureList.length; i++) {
    var picSecond = pictureList[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < picSecond.length; j++) {
        alert("picSecond[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + picSecond[j]);
    }
}
```

on your select box, create a onChange event and call a method. The value of the option selected should be passed in the onChange event. You can use the above loop to easily get the nth element from the array by easily tweaking the code a bit.

Now you can create a method to dynamically create you img tags, with the src attribute as picSecond[j] value from your array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is javascript code which you need,
You just need jquery

```
pictureList[$( "#animal" ).val()].forEach(function(elm){
  $("#slider").append('<li><img class="imageClass" src="'+elm+'"/></li>')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
function changeAnimal(val){

document.getElementById('slider').innerHTML = '';
if(val !== ''){

    for(i=0;i<pictureList[val-1].length;i++){

        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = pictureList[val-1][i];
        li.appendChild(img);            
        document.getElementById('slider').appendChild(li);
    }

}    
}
```

**[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qvGpV/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I've created a working JSFiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n9NzF/5/).

Javascript

```
var pictureList = [
    ["images/img1.jpg","images/img2.jpg"],
    ["images/img3.jpg","images/img4.jpg", "images/img5.jpg"],
    ["images/img6.jpg"]
];

var elem = document.getElementById("animal");
elem.onchange = function(){
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
    slider.innerHTML = "";
    var val = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
    for (var key in pictureList[val-1]){
        var newItem = '<li><img class="imageClass" src="'+(pictureList[val-1][key])+'"/></li>';
        slider.innerHTML += newItem;
    }
};
```

HTML

```
<select id="animal">
    <option>Choose animal </option>
    <option value="1">animal 1 </option>
    <option value="2">animal 2</option>
    <option value="3">animal 3 </option>
</select>

<ul id="slider"></ul>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code with real image sources: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/n9NzF/3/). In the result, option 2 shows images from first 2 rows and option 3 - images from all 3 rows

Comment: Great, what was your result? You just linked to my link.

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle in my answer. [Try this one](http://jsfiddle.net/n9NzF/5/)